# Problem After Permission Change in Publish App

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have a android app in play store. That has only internet permission. Now I change in app user can use their camera & storage.
I add privacy policy on play store and in link in app also. I also mention these permission in release text.
When I upload new app display message like this

```
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 4
    versionName "4.0"
```

Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Permission Code

```
private void permission(){
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(StartActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
        //Display_Rermission_Reason();
    }else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, PrivacyPolicyActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            // close the app
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry!!!, you can't use this app without granting permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Display_Rermission_Reason();
        }
    }
}
```

After publish the app it display in google play store

```
This app is incompatible with all of your devices.
```

Any version 5+ and above

Comment: SORRY WARNING MESSAGE IS... New Permissions Add... Users that have the APK with version code 2 may need to accept one or more of the android permission. CAMERA  and android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions, which may result in them not upgrading to this version of the app

Comment: Ignore that warning cuz they need to accept that anyway in order to use this app.

Answer (score 0):

Change this in `manifest`,

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full"
android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
android:required="false" />
```

Have a look at this link below which might help you,

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element

Comment: i am using camera facility....... user can take image with auto focus so this can not be disable

Comment: yeah sure we all use camera facility.. "user can take image with auto focus so this can not be disable" - do it inside your activity to check that not in manifest..
Just try this and publish app will work fine..

Comment: maybe explaining what this code does would make it easier for the user to understand why they need it in order to make their app work

Comment: @NikosHidalgo as much as I would love to there's no proper documentation provided as to why it disables for all devices when you use that tag. Although, android does recommend providing it explicitly.. However, I updated the answer with the link thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: Thanks for the link! So essentially what this code does is disable the automatic filtering that the play store has, so that the app can be accepted for all users, even the ones who have installed it previously without the camera related permissions. I guess that's why it's important then to check programmatically that a feature is available to cover all bases.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo But i Don't understand why giving that `<uses-feature` does show that its available to none of the devices when it is important to give that in the `manifest`. Well it is somewhat similar to not giving when I add required?

Comment: I think you still have to explicitly declare it even though you mention that the feature is not required, for compatibility purposes concerning the play store filtering

Comment: @NikosHidalgo yeah but is that the right thing? Because using `android.hardware.camera2` does not appear to be showing any devices, then which devices use that h/w? Any documentation on that?

Comment: Not sure. This was just my take on what I read from the initial documentation link posted.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo yeah like I said lack of documentation.. in that case they could at least mention that providing `android:required="false"` is mandatory. Although it is not superimposed to provide `<uses-feature` but always recommended.